# Super class access to a default class from another package

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, reflection

I am trying to create a reusable template class for my unit test cases.  Suppose classes Sample, and SampleTest belong to the same package, while Template belongs to a different package.  I get error instantiating Sample class.  I expect the method will be executed as if it were a method of the SampleTest class that have access to Sample.  Are there ways to make this work?

```
public SampleTest extends Template<Sample> {
     public void testMethod() {
          getTarget().method();
     }
}

public class Template<T> extends TestCase {

    /** Spied, object instance to test. */
    private transient T targetObject;

    /** Test class type to be derived as parameter type of test subclass. */
    private transient final Class<T> targetType;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();
        setupTargetObject();
    }

    protected void setupTargetObject()
    {
        final T realObject =  targetType.newInstance(); //ERROR here if class under test is non-public
        targetObject = Mockito.spy(realObject);
    }

    protected Template() {
            final ParameterizedType paramedType = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            targetType = (Class<T>) paramedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected T getTarget()
    {
        return targetObject;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try this. `Constructor<?> c = targetType.getConstructors()[0]; c.setAccessible(true); Object realObject = c.newInstance();`

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  I am a little confused because I tried that before posting here and got Security Exception.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Java prevents calling any non-public method (and thus, constructor) of a class in a different package. This is prevented by the compiler *and* the JVM.
Hence you can't call these methods directly, and, as in your case, you can't call these methods via Java Reflection API.

A solution would be, as suggested, to use setAccessible(true) on the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, I would recommend giving the responsibility of creating instance to the Sub-class through an abstract method. You can then wrap it for spying on that instance.